# Component identfication for IC marked C50 23XH

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount, led-driver

[image]

The letters on the chip are:

C50

23XH

What is the producer of this chip? What is this IC?

Comment: Some more context might help. What sort of circuit it is being used in? What does it have connected to it? etc ...

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please see [this Meta post](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines?cb=1) on identification questions. You can [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/397058/edit) your question to include the `identification` tag, and you should add as much info as you can about what circuit/device this chip came from.

Comment: You should also add the part number (or whatever) into the title. Someone might recognise it and answer whereas your "this chip" doesn't give any clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly looking at a TI op amp part [OPA350EA/2K5](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/OPA350EA-2K5/296-46161-1-ND/7033336). Per the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa350.pdf) the markings on this package are C50. It also is a 8VSSOP which matches the package shown. You should be able to use the data sheet to verify your pinout and see if this matches your circuit.